# Image processing - How can I apply an operation to several images at once?

Tags: image-processing, string-manipulation

I imported pictures into *Mathematica*, and used names for them that follow the easy scheme "name" string joined with an integer, ranging from 14 to 20. Printing these images on screen works nicely:

```
Do[Print[ToExpression[StringJoin["name", ToString[i]]]], {i, 14, 20}]
```

However, applying operations like `ColorNegate[]` or `ColorReplace[]` instead of `Print[]` will result in neither any output nor error message. Is it possible to process several images at once?

Comment: Use `Table[]`, and store the result somewhere else?

Comment: Maybe I was not specific enough: I would like to print out the processed images on screen to see the result of an operation (filtering, color changing etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be better to use `Table[]` instead, so you can still use the processed images later:

```
girls = Table[ImageEffect[ExampleData[{"TestImage", img}], "Charcoal"],
              {img, {"Elaine", "Lena", "Tiffany"}}]
```

[image: girls in charcoal]

so for instance `girls[[2]]` gives Lenna in charcoal.

For your specific example,

```
Table[ColorNegate[ToExpression["name" <> ToString[i]]], {i, 14, 20}]
```

Comment: +1 naming schemes like "stringNNN" aren't usually a good idea

Comment: This solution is very efficient, thanks! @belisarius Could you explain why?

Comment: @R.S., unless you have a good justification for indexing your pics, you should use more descriptive names for them instead.

Comment: Ok got it - I simplified my example of course. The original dataset is a confocal z-stack of a stem cell cluster, where I included the "slice distance" (usually in micrometers) as integers in the filename. Legit enough? You decide!

Comment: @R.S., Ah, then certainly justifiable! :) The problem is with things like lazy photographers not bothering to change the default file names after grabbing the pics from their fine camera...

Comment: @J.M Also - you just made me download all these mathematica girls, and judged from a distance, Tiffany is definitely holding a banana. I thank god everybody here has left already.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Do` doesn't return anything so you just need to prepend `Print` to your function to see the result: 
`Do[Print@ColorNegate[ToExpression[StringJoin["name", ToString[i]]]], {i, 14, 20}]`

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Could you give me a hint what the @ means? Never saw it before in MMA code.

Comment: You can answer this yourself. Whenever you don't know what something means in Mathematica, highlight it and press f1. It will display the help file for that item. So you can read all about `Prefix`, in this case.